# Leiningen: How to set Maven groupId and packaging properties in project.clj

Tags: maven, clojure, leiningen

I have a Clojure project that I would like to package and use in one of my Java projects that uses Maven.

When I generate a pom.xml file using Leiningen, it sets the groupId to artifactId, but I need the groupId to be the same as my parent Java project.

Also, I would like to be able to specify the packaging type in the pom.xml to be jar

In short: how do I set the groupId and packaging properties in project.clj to generate a pom.xml containing those properties?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Leiningen uses the `groupId/artifactId` naming convention to distinguish between the two entities. Look at the [sample project.clj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/sample.project.clj) to see how it's done. When running `lein pom` `groupId` and `artifactId` will be then properly resolved.

Sample snippet from the linked `project.clj`:

```
;; The project is named "sample", and its group-id is "org.example".
(defproject org.example/sample "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" ; version "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
;; ...
```

EDIT: I missed the question about packaging. AFAICS you can't specify the packaging property in `project.clj`.